# How can i get the filename from a string type link

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, uri

With Retrofit, I get the url data in string data type, but I need the file name inside the url, how can I get it?

I've visited many websites but I couldn't find any results about it.

Comment: Try this `url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in Kotlin

```
url.substringAfterLast("/").substringBeforeLast(".")
```